# Excel Power Query decouple and unpivot columns

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, get-transform

I have a data structure that is something comparable to this

```
| type | A-metric1 | A-metric2 | B-metric1 | B-metric2 |
| aRow |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |
```

I'd like to turn A and B into a dimensions and turn it into rows so that it's something like this

```
| type | dimension | metric1 | metric2 |
| aRow |     A     |    1    |    2    |
| aRow |     B     |    3    |    4    |
```

I could probably do this manually by duplicating the type row for as many times as there are dimension labels, and then extract the metrics by order and do this in excel with a macro.

However I am likely to be handling large files, and probably can't manipulate data of this size effecitvely in VBA. I was wondering if something like this is possible to do in Excels Power Query / Get & Transform?

Sorry if duplicate - Im not sure how to formulate this question to get relevant hits on searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply following approach:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"type"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    split = Table.SplitColumn(unpivot, "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", 1), {"dimension", "metric"}),
    pivot = Table.Pivot(split, List.Distinct(split[metric]), "metric", "Value")
in
    pivot
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, it will take me a while to understand what each statement does, I hope you understand that I will refrain to accept this answer at this moment for that reason? Otherwise thank you.